# Should we allow LMGTFY links?

Tags: discussion

LMGTFY = Let Me Google That For You. It simulates typing a search term and clicking the search button in Google. *And* it ends with an IMO belittling "Was that so hard?".

In a comment to [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/17317/are-aa-to-usb-direct-chargers-safe/17322#17322) answerer added a link to LMGTFY. Also because he hid it in a TinyURL link, so that you wouldn't know it before you clicked it, to me it looked like it was meant to ridicule the user who asked for a link, which definitely was a reasonable request.

When TinyURL is used it's not easy to readily recognize them, but shouldn't LMGTFY links be banned?

Comment: I downvoted that answer because, when offering him a chance to improve it by adding a link, answerer replied with the LMGTFY. The only difference with Google is indeed the belittling "was that so hard?". Kevin suggests not to take it personally, but it's *meant* to be taken personally. I vote for banning too.

Comment: @steven - I suppose I should have said "don't take the bait", or "don't feed the trolls".  You jumped right in to the mud to throw back a comment dripping in sarcasm and proclaimed your downvote on the answer, which didn't solve anything.  Please just flag the comment next time.

Comment: @Kevin - I'll try that, but I'm not promising anything! :-). Thanks

Comment: @Stevenvh, it could also just be someone learning the ropes. If the same user does that twice the action taken will be more then just removing the comment and teaching in another comment. Please remember, you have pretty high rights and flags get our attention quickly.

Comment: @Kortuk - IMO answerer did it on purpose. I suggested to add a link to the answer, and I presume that any benevolent person would do so, and not add a LMGTFY link. Maybe I'm too naive. I'm still young... ;-). But don't worry, next time I'll flag it, and leave the rest to you guys.

Comment: @Stevenvh, we are normally light handed on these things though the first time. It may seem like an odd approach for us, but it is how we are.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, they should be banned, and are already banned elsewhere. We don't like putting up "no elephants" signs until we have an actual problem with elephants first..

[Ban LMGTFY (let me google that for you) links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links)

I'd treat this as an education issue first, then if it's a persistent issue only resort to the blacklisting of the domain site-wide.

Comment: Although I am not against a ban from a technical perspective, LMGTFY links have not been a big issue here. I think this is probably the first link I have seen in over a year.

Comment: @Jeff, They also had to hide the link with a URL shortener to get it through unnoticed for so long. I have had maybe 2 flags for LMGTFY links in the past 9 months and they were both letting me know someone was using one. This is not a major issue for a site, just a case of new community members needing to be taught the ropes.